# Acceder a formularios (Angular) desde consola chrome

Tags: javascript, angular

quiero automatizar una tarea repetitiva. Yo tengo un formulario que esta hecho con angular. Pero cada tanto tengo que cargar unos datos para seguir trabajando. Mi idea era hacer un script y ejecutarlo desde la consola de chrome. Si bien puedo acceder a los botones para abrir los selects o cerrar el modal. No se como cambiarle el valor a un input, ya que si bien puedo hacerlo con:

```
document.getElementById('mat-input-2').value = 20000
```

No se actualizan los valores en el formulario y queda vacio

Comment: No se a que te refieres con que no se actualizan los valores en el formulario. A mi me funciona tu método: https://jsfiddle.net/f2up9a47/  (si abres la consola y ejecutas esa linea cambiando el valor, este cambia bien).  Revisa bien los ids a ver si estan mal o algo.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que estes utilizando reactive forms? Si es asi para cambiar los valores deberia usar la libreria.
Tambien puede ser que estes usando ngModel